# Sending UDP data from local port to local port

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to send data to my own local port using UDP packet.

For this I use boost::asio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using boost::asio::ip::address;

boost::asio::io_service _ioServiceOut;
std::shared_ptr<udp::socket> _socketOut;
std::shared_ptr<udp::endpoint> _endpointOut;

static int PortOut = 32676;
static std::string Loopback = "127.0.0.1";

int main()
{
    _endpointOut = std::make_shared<udp::endpoint>(address::from_string(Loopback), PortOut);
    _socketOut = std::make_shared<udp::socket>(_ioServiceOut, *_endpointOut.get());


    _socketOut->send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer("0"), *(_endpointOut.get())
    );

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, it sends from 32676 to 32676 and my other application that is listening to this port, can't receive the message then.

When writin a similar application in C#, the Net.Socket assigns a random port as the outcoming one.
How can I achieve the same effect with boost::asio?

[image]

Comment: The two lines you have shown don't send anything. We need a [mcve]

Comment: > "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code"
It's not caused by my code, or at least the question is not code relevant, but well, as you wish...

Comment: "When writin a similar application in C#, the Net.Socket assigns a random port as the outcoming one." asio doesn't because you pass a specific endpoint to its constructor to bind to.

Comment: @tkausl, do you see the Wireshark output? If you set an output port to 32676 in a C# app, it sends from random (53889 in this case) to 32676. Asio uses the same port for both ends. That's what the question is: how can I set the port asio will use as the source (not the destination!).

Comment: I do see the wireshark output, yes. And I do see that you set the remotr port in your `send_to` call __and__ set the same endpoint as local port to your socket. "how can I set the port asio will use as the source (not the destination!)"  you pass it to the constructor to the socket.

Comment: OHHHH, so that's how it;s supposed to work! Now I get it. Thanks and sory I didn't get it at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to tkausl I figured out the problem is the Output socked initialization. If you want your system to assing you a free port, just create a new endpoint setting the port to 0.

```
_socketOut = std::make_shared<udp::socket>(_ioServiceOut, new udp::endpoint(address::from_string(Loopback), 0));
```